# Does the 2012 election add to the moderators or replace them?

Tags: support, status-completed, election

Are we voting to *add* moderators, or are we voting on a complete slate (so existing moderators need to nominate themselves if they want to continue)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The elected moderators will replace the current moderators.

Moderators for beta sites are all *appointed* and not selected by the community. These are positions to be held until the community has grown enough to elect their own moderators (i.e., graduation). As every beta graduates, new, permanent moderators are elected.